# Tcp over TLS with Akka BidiFlow

Tags: java, scala, akka, tls1.2, akka-stream

We are trying to add TLS support for Tcp in Akka using BidiFlow. We managed to establish connections, and pass messages, however, there seems to be parts of the handshake that we cannot understand.

Apparently, the restrictions we made in the code (such as only TLSv1.2, and 4 specific ciphersuites) are not applying at the handshake level, but we do see errors when trying to pass messages when the restrictions are not respected. This means, a TLSv1 client can connect to a our TLSv1.2 server (we just see a `closing output` in the log) but the client is not notified that the protocol isn't supported (same with unsupported ciphersuites); messages DO NOT pass through tho.

During a TLS analysis, all tools report as if the server supported TLSv1, v1.1, etc while we only want v1.2

We found that the only way we can really restrict the connection is to add the filters in the `java.security` file in the jdk.

Is this the expected behavior?

Here's the code that performs the negotiation:

```
object Tls {

  def getGraph(tlsConfig: TlsConfig, role: TLSRole):
  BidiFlow[ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = {
    val sslContext = createSslContext(tlsConfig)
    val firstSession = createFirstSession(sslContext)
    createGraph(sslContext, firstSession, role)
  }

  private def createFirstSession(sslContext: SSLContext): NegotiateNewSession = {
    val negotiatedSession = TLSProtocol.NegotiateNewSession
      .withProtocols("TLSv1.2")
      .withCipherSuites(
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
      )
      .withParameters(sslContext.getDefaultSSLParameters)

    negotiatedSession
  }

  private def createSslContext(tlsConfig: TlsConfig): SSLContext = {
    val ksTrust = createKeyStore(tlsConfig.trustStoreType, tlsConfig.trustStoreFile, tlsConfig.trustStorePass)
    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
    trustManagerFactory.init(ksTrust)

    val ksKeys = createKeyStore(tlsConfig.keyStoreType, tlsConfig.keyStoreFile, tlsConfig.keyStorePass)
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
    keyManagerFactory.init(ksKeys, tlsConfig.keyStorePass.toCharArray)

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom)
    sslContext
  }

  private def createKeyStore(storeType: String, file: String, password: String): KeyStore = {
    val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType)
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), password.toCharArray)
    keyStore
  }

  private def createGraph(
                           sslContext: SSLContext,
                           firstSession: NegotiateNewSession,
                           role: TLSRole)
  : BidiFlow[ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = {

    val tls: BidiFlow[TLSProtocol.SslTlsOutbound, ByteString, ByteString, TLSProtocol.SslTlsInbound, NotUsed] =
      TLS(sslContext, firstSession, role)

    val tlsSupport: BidiFlow[ByteString, TLSProtocol.SslTlsOutbound, TLSProtocol.SslTlsInbound, ByteString, NotUsed] =
      BidiFlow.fromFlows(
        Flow[ByteString].map(TLSProtocol.SendBytes),
        Flow[TLSProtocol.SslTlsInbound].map {
          case TLSProtocol.SessionBytes(_, bytes) => bytes
          case TLSProtocol.SessionTruncated =>
            throw ProcessingException("TLS session truncated")
          case _ =>
            throw ProcessingException("Unexpected type received from TLS pipeline")
        })

    tlsSupport.atop(tls)
  }
}
```

Comment: akka-stream has support for TLS. Have you checked `akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS` before implementing your own BidiFlow?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc not really, I grabbed the code half done and added the "filters" of TLSv1.2 and ciphersuites.

Comment: I'd suggest to check if it can be applied to your use case and adapt to default TLS support if possible. Check out source code of  `Http(actorSystem).cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps` as it does support TLS for http connection in `akka-http`.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc I know the guys that started coding this used a custom BidiFlow as we needed fine grained control over Tcp connections, which is either hard or impossible using the default TLS support in akka.

Comment: Not sure what kind of control is required but the default implementation of Tls is using https://github.com/lightbend/ssl-config/ and this provides strong configuration bases for the cyphers, trusted stores and key mangers.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc thanks. Regardless the default implementation possibly having better options, BidiFlow should emit errors at the handshake level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184763/discussion-between-fede-e-and-ivan-stanislavciuc).